# How to fade out, set value, fade in; but do it 'better'

Tags: jquery, effect

Say a element has value 55:

```
<span id="some">55</span>
```

I want to:

1. fade out the element
2. set value 44
3. fade in the element

So I tried:

```
$("#some").fadeOut("slow").html("44").fadeIn("slow");
```

But the above *first sets the span's content* to 44, *and then* fades out and fades in.

So I tried with a callback:

```
function fadeOutComplete(){
  $("#some").html("<%= @cc %>").fadeIn("slow");
}
$("#some").fadeOut("slow",fadeOutComplete);
```

Now this works, but it's looks and feels clunky. Is there some way to write this DRYer and more *jQuery-er*? (not even sure what I mean by *jQuery-er*!)

How could I pass in the element whose value is to be set and the value to be set to `fadeOutComplete` so I can make that callback sort-of generic?

Comment: I don't know, but would also like to know how do you accomplish passing a value to a callback, something like '$("#some").fadeOut("slow",fadeOutComplete(44));'. Can use a global variable that gets set by the caller and read by the callback, but that's like 1980's programming style.

Comment: and here's how that's done - [JQuery pass more parameters into callback](http://stackoverflow.com/q/939032/374556)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Check this...

```
$("#some").fadeOut("slow", function() {
   $(this).html("<%= @cc %>").fadeIn("slow");
});
```

- You can pass an anonymous function, to prevent registering a named function that will no doubt only be used once.
- Inside the callback of the complete for `fadeOut()`, `this` is pointing to the native DOM element. This allows you to reference it again in a DRY way.

Answer (score 5):

Same approach but with some cleanliness:

```
$('#some').fadeOut('slow',function(){
     $(this).html('somehtml').fadeIn('slow');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

try like this:

```
$('#some').fadeOut('slow',function(){
$('#some').html('somehtml');
$('#some').fadeIn('slow');
});
```

Comment: Repeating the same selector 3 times isn't very DRY.

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem with the fade command.  The command runs asyncronous, meaning while it is fading out the text is being changed.  Look at this question for an answer:  [jQuery synchronous operation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/829355/jquery-synchronous-operation)

Comment: The callback has access to its parent's scope.

Comment: I was thinking about jquery's ajax callbacks, My bad.